# Copy first 10 objects of NSMutableArray to another NSMutable Array

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray of 35 items and I want to copy the first 10 items to another array.

After adding 10 items to my array I want to add the same 10 items again.

Please suggest how could I do it.

Code :

i have initialize the array having all images in this way

```
    self.arrayAllAnimalImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"bagheera.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"baloo.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"bear.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"bird.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"camel.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"cock.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"deer.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"dolphin.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"donkey.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"elephant.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"fish.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"flamigo.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"frog.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"girraf.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"hippo.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"monkey.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"octopus.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"owl.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"panda.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"parrot.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"peacock.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"penguin.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"piglet.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"polarbear.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"pumba.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"rabbit.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"redpanda.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"seahorse.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"simba.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"snake.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"starfish.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"tiger.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"tigger.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"turtle.jpg"];
[self.arrayAllAnimalImages addObject:@"whale.jpg"];
```

I want 10 items from the above array randomly so Here I have a shuffled array

```
for (int i = 0; i<[arrayAllAnimalImages count] ;i++)
    {
        NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [arrayAllAnimalImages  count];
        [arrayAllAnimalImages  exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:randomIndex];  


    }
```

Now I want these 10 items to add in an empty array I initialize here :

```
if (LevelCount ==2)
{
    self.arrayLevelImages= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if ([arrayLevelImages count] > 0)
    {
        [arrayLevelImages removeAllObjects];
    }
```

Now here I want to add the first 10 objects of arrayAllAnimalImages.

After adding First 10 items, I want to add the same previous 10 items again to arrayLevelImages.

```
}
```

Please Help !!!!!

Comment: Please clarify the second part of your question: are you saying that after you add the first 10 items to the second array, you want to add the same 10 items from the first array to the second array again?

Comment: Classical question: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
NSArray *tempArray = [arrayAllAnimalImages subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
[arrayLevelImages addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];
[arrayLevelImages addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];
```

Comment: Great Answer. It save my time. Perfect Solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *arrayLevelImages = [[arrayAllAnimalImages 
                              subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 10)] mutableCopy];
```